# nodejs, Store Data in Cassandra using helenus

Tags: node.js, cassandra, thrift, helenus

I am trying to implement interfacing for storing data to cassandra using helenus module.
Using thrift driver, I am inserting and getting the data.

```
                keySpace.get(cfName, function (err, cf) {
                    cf.insert(key, storData, {consistency :
                              helenus.ConsistencyLevel.ANY}, function(err) {
               }
```

Now I am getting the data as below:

```
               keySpace.get(cfName, function (err, cf) {
                    cf.get(key, function(err, row) {
                       row.forEach(function(name,value,ts,ttl){
                       console.log("Getting NAME AS:", name.toString(),
                                   value.toString());
                    });
                });
```

But what I am observing is if the data stored is JSON level 1, then I am able to retrieve the data correctly, as for example:

```
                {"a":"b", "c":"d"}
```

This I am able to retrieve using above get operation, but if it is multi level, then I am getting the data as [Object Object],
example JSON:

```
         {"c": [{"a":"b"}]}
```

This is not working for me.
Please let me know where I am doing mistake.

Regards,
-M-

Answer (score 2):

The string representation of an object is `[Object Object]`, so when you have nested objects, that's what `toString()` will return.

You should be using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` instead, and if the name is never nested, you could do

```
keySpace.get(cfName, function (err, cf) {
     cf.get(key, function(err, row) {
         row.forEach(function(name,value,ts,ttl){
         console.log("Getting NAME AS:", name.toString(), JSON.stringify(value));
     });
});
```

basically the proper way to store JSON is to stringify it first, then when you're getting it back you parse it.

As a sidenote, why aren't you using CQL, it's a lot easier to work with compared to thrift

Comment: While storing the data, I am storing in JSON.strified format, but while getting the data, it is not coming properly in case of more than one level of JSON data, So I am thinking if consistencyLevel needs to set some thing different value or not. I will try with CQL parallelly.

Comment: As long you're storing a string, and you're using `JSON.stringify()` and not `toString()`, consistency levels or returning `[Object, Object]` shouldn't be an issue.